# Unable to execute jenkins.war in command Prompt

Tags: jenkins

[Remaining log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsJFM.png)Navigated to folder where my .war is located and executed 'java -jar jenkins.war'.Then this is the error i am getting while i am executing in cmd.

`Unable to run Jenkins.war in cmd,These is the whole log

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurredWARNING: Illegal reflective access by Main (file:/C:/Self%20Learning/Jenkins/jenkins.war) to field java.util.zip.ZipFile.nameWARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of MainWARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operationsWARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future releaseRunning from: C:\Self Learning\Jenkins\jenkins.warwebroot: $user.home/.jenkins33mFeb 22, 2018 12:38:13 PM Main deleteWinstoneTempContentsWARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file C:\Users\bchalla\AppData\Local\Temp\winstone\jenkins.war0mFeb 22, 2018 12:38:13 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initializedINFO: Logging initialized @704ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLogFeb 22, 2018 12:38:13 PM winstone.Logger logInternalINFO: Beginning extraction from war file33mFeb 22, 2018 12:38:16 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPathWARNING: Empty contextPath[0mFeb 22, 2018 12:38:16 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStartINFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOTFeb 22, 2018 12:38:18 PM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor visitServletINFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServletFeb 22, 2018 12:38:18 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStartINFO: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0Feb 22, 2018 12:38:18 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStartINFO: No SessionScavenger set, using defaultsFeb 22, 2018 12:38:18 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper startScavengingINFO: Scavenging every 660000msJenkins home directory: C:\Users\bchalla\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkinsFeb 22, 2018 12:38:19 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStartINFO: Startedw.@f1a45f8{/,file:///C:/Users/bchalla/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}C:\Users\bchalla\.jenkins\war}Feb 22, 2018 12:38:19 PMorg.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStopINFO: StoppedServerConnector@270b6b5e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}Feb 22, 2018 12:38:19 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper stopScavengingINFO: Stopped scavengingfeb 22, 2018 12:38:19 PM hudson.WebAppMain contextDestroyedINFO: Shutting down a Jenkins instance that was still starting ujava.lang.Throwable: reasonat hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:388)atorg.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:898)at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ServletContextHandler.java:545)atorg.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.stopContext(ContextHandler.java:873)atorg.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.stopContext(ServletContextHandler.java:355)atorg.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1507)at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopContext(WebAppContext.java:1471 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:927)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
    at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:307)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:167)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at Main._main(Main.java:294)
    at Main.main(Main.java:132)Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" Feb 22, 2018 12:38:19 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStopINFO: Stopped w.@f1a45f8{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Users\bchalla\.jenkins\war}java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:560)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 moreFeb 22, 2018 12:38:19 PM winstone.Logger logInternalINFO: Winstone shutdown successfullyjava.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at Main._main(Main.java:294)
    at Main.main(Main.java:132)Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at
```

'

Comment: Can you please add the whole log???

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check in the processes if any other instance of Jenkins is running, also if there are any, please kill all of them start command prompt in admin mode and then try executing command again.

You can also check if the port is being occupied by some other process.